# Java was started but returned exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse

Both eclipse and jdk are 64 bit.

Environment variables:

```
classpath: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib
path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin
```

I added the these lines to my eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

My java version details:

```
C:\Users\Owner>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

My eclipse.ini file:
I have edited the required version from 1.5 to 1.7

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
```

The Error Details:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar 
C:\ECLIPSE\ECLIPSE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher C:\ECLIPSE\ECLIPSE\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library 
C:\ECLIPSE\ECLIPSE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.
v20120502\eclipse_1406.dll
-startup 
C:\ECLIPSE\ECLIPSE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 19b4_60
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
C:\ECLIPSE\ECLIPSE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

Please help. I have tried re-installing everything twice. Nothing has helped.

Comment: You'll need a maximum heap size larger than 384MB for anything useful. Which eclipse file did you download?

Comment: Your `--launcher.library` specifies a 32 bit jar.

Comment: That arch value also indicates a 32-bit Eclipse.

Comment: The name says: Java 7 Update 45 (64-bit) and Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 45(64-bit) @greg-449 I am sure both are 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

and it seems like the eclipse.ini file has been manupilated before
you have a 32 bit jvm, but your requirements are that of a 64 bit
use the x86 java.exe n check if it works by that i mean use the ProgramFilesx86 path